# porting parallel code with furture from mac to windows fails

Tags: r, future, raster, r-sf

I am extracting data from a raster using the `raster::extract` function and a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`as template.

I use future_lapply to do this in parallel. The repex below runs perfectly fine and gives the expected results on my local mac, but when exporting it to a widows machine with more cores, it fails with

```
Error in as(from, "Spatial") : 
  no method or default for coercing "sf" to "Spatial"
```

it seem that the method is somehow not exported correctly on windows?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(future.apply)

# make raster
ras <- raster(ncol=25, nrow=25, xmn=0, xmx=25, ymn=0, ymx=25)
ras[]=seq(1,ncell(ras),1)
crs(ras) <- "+proj=utm +zone=51 ellps=WGS84"

# make SpatialPointsDataFrame with 10 "maps" à 3 points
coords <- matrix(sample(5:20,6*10,replace = TRUE), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
data <- tibble(maps = rep(paste("map", c(1:10), sep = ""), each = 3),
               points = rep(paste("p", c(1:3)), 10))

spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coords,
                               data = data, 
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=51 ellps=WGS84")) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

# extract data for points in each map from raster
maps <- unique(spdf$maps)

plan(multiprocess)

future_lapply(maps, function(x) {

    filter(spdf, maps == x) %>%
    raster::extract(x = ras, y =  .)

  })
```

`plan(cluster)` works, but looking at the task-manager it doesn't seem to create multiple processes but runs on a single core

Mac:

```
> session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
 os       macOS Mojave 10.14          
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Stockholm            
 date     2019-09-25                  

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package      * version date       lib source        
 assertthat     0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 backports      1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 class          7.3-15  2019-01-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 classInt       0.3-1   2018-12-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 cli            1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 codetools      0.2-16  2018-12-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 crayon         1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 DBI            1.0.0   2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 digest         0.6.19  2019-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 dplyr        * 0.8.0.1 2019-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 e1071          1.7-1   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 fansi          0.4.0   2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 future       * 1.12.0  2019-03-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 future.apply * 1.2.0   2019-03-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 globals        0.12.4  2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 glue           1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 lattice        0.20-38 2018-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 listenv        0.7.0   2018-01-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 magrittr       1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 pillar         1.4.1   2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 pkgconfig      2.0.2   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 purrr          0.3.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 R6             2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 raster       * 2.8-19  2019-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 Rcpp           1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rgdal          1.4-3   2019-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rlang          0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rstudioapi     0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 sessioninfo  * 1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 sf           * 0.7-3   2019-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 sp           * 1.3-1   2018-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 tibble       * 2.1.3   2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 tidyselect     0.2.5   2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 units          0.6-2   2018-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 utf8           1.1.4   2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 vctrs          0.1.0   2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 withr          2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 yaml           2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 zeallot        0.1.0   2018-01-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
```

Windows:

```
> session_info()
- Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_Germany.1252        
 ctype    English_Germany.1252        
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2019-09-25                  

- Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package      * version date       lib source        
 assertthat     0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 class          7.3-15  2019-01-01 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 classInt       0.3-3   2019-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 cli            1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 codetools      0.2-16  2018-12-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 crayon         1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 DBI            1.0.0   2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 digest         0.6.19  2019-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 dplyr        * 0.8.1   2019-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 e1071          1.7-1   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 future       * 1.13.0  2019-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 future.apply * 1.2.0   2019-03-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 globals        0.12.4  2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 glue           1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 KernSmooth     2.23-15 2015-06-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 lattice        0.20-38 2018-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 listenv        0.7.0   2018-01-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 magrittr       1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pillar         1.4.1   2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 pkgconfig      2.0.2   2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 purrr          0.3.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 R6             2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 raster       * 2.9-5   2019-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 Rcpp           1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rgdal          1.4-3   2019-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 rlang          0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sessioninfo  * 1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
 sf           * 0.7-4   2019-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 sp           * 1.3-1   2018-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 tibble         2.1.1   2019-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 tidyselect     0.2.5   2018-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 units          0.6-3   2019-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
 withr          2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

Comment: Have you tried forcing multiple sessions by using `multisession` rather than `multiprocess`?

Comment: I have not used "future.apply" package.  If it similar to the "parallel" package, then the way Mac and Windows sets up and handles the multicores are different and the code is not directly transferrable.  You'll have to go back to the documentation to confirm.

Comment: @DaveT that's (in theory) the beauty of future.apply. It solves this things for you. From the doc: multiprocess: If multicore evaluation is supported, that will be used, otherwise multisession evaluation will be used. (note: multicore is not soupported on windows so it will default to multisession)

Comment: @Oliver Yes i have, it doesn't make a difference. I think both successfully create multiple sessions (and some code runs) but somehow this method is not exported on windows